# SnapKit snp can't assign to UIHostingController

Tags: swift, swiftui, snapkit

On many of projects I use SnapKit. And on new project too. On project I have ViewController which connected with SwiftUI view:

```swift
class OfficeListViewController: UIViewController {
 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: OfficeListView())
   addChild(vc)
   view.addSubview(vc.view)
   vc.didMove(toParent: self)
   vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   // Here I want to set constraints to vc
   vc.snp // throws error: Value of type 'UIHostingController<OfficeView>' has no member 'snp'
 }
}

struct OfficeListView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("View")
  }
}
```

But it throws error:

> Value of type 'UIHostingController' has no member 'snp'

How to correctly use SnapKit with it?

Comment: `UIHostingController` is just subclass of `UIViewController`. I don't know what do you mean by `vc.snp`, but if you want to set up constrains then use `vc.view` as usually we do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIHostingController` is just subclass of `UIViewController` and it renders SwiftUI view inside regular `UIView`. If you want to set up constrains, then you should use `vc.view` as we usually do with views.